# TeamCity Building Android App but cannot find symbol

Tags: android, intellij-idea, teamcity, analytics

I have an android studio project which has 4 different flavors, each flavor has its own res/xml folder with global_tracker.xml (Google Analytics). Generating signed apk successfully creates the apk without error, and it's functionally doing what I expect. But TeamCity gives an error saying it cannot find the symbol: global_tracker.xml. I checked the source code from which it wants to build from, and the file exists in the proper folder and location.

Comment: How are you running the build? Gradle runner I assume? Which tasks? Are you using the gradle wrapper or the default gradle installation?

This error should mean that when generating the R.java file during resource processing, it's not picking up the xml file or not generating the entry for it. This might be due to the file not being there (seems not to be your case), it containing errors or gradle not picking it up for reasons (file cached, for example). Have you tried running the "clean" task first?

Comment: Managed to overcome by this with creating 4 different named xml files, instead of 4 different folders for the same named xmls